# why does my parent to 3 vertices object jump on my chain animation?

Tags: modifiers

I have made a chain animation with array + curve modifier.

I applied the array modifier and i am moving the chain by the y-value via drivers (a custom scene property).

I parented the object to the chain via 3 vertices, but on frame 55 it "jumps" weirdly. I have no idea why.

Why is that and how can i repair it?

[image]

blend file:
[image]

Comment: Your Chain part is being deformed by the Curve modifier and the parent vertices are distorted in such a way that causes the child object to flip at that specific point. The elements are being deformed by the curves which is visible in top view. If this is not important then you should consider using an Empty with Follow Path Constraint and parent the 3 Bars to it. The offset of the Follow path could also use a driver.  Here is your blend file with the above adjustments https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=n4Pk4rJB You should consider another way of animating to avoid bending .

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need help setting up a simple roller chain rig.

Comment: of course...just tell me how you would do it! I love learning new ways!

Comment: With a little bit of delay here are two posts about Follow Path and Bike Chain that you may find useful: https://curiousblends.blogspot.com/2023/11/drivers-match-curve-modifier-position.html and https://curiousblends.blogspot.com/2023/11/creating-roller-bike-chain-rig.html

Comment: thank you! nice site you made there!!!